# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource. can Not create Beanfactory

Tags: spring-boot, mysql-connector, beancreationexception

I have tried to connect with database but every time I got an exception called BeanCreationException. here I am attaching the properties file and and pom.xml. I also have created CRUDRepository. I have tried but cann't find the solution. In STS ide com.mysql dependency only work. but also tried in eclipse used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>`your text`
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>`your text`
```

but there also come same error comes.

Here is my application properties file attached below

```
spring.datasource.name=pkdb1
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pkdb1?serverTimeZone=UTC
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pkdb1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Passw0rd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update



spring.jpa.show-sql=true


#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>STSProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You should also post the whole stacktrace, so it is possible to understand why it is not possible to create the bean.